How can I fix readonly database error in an exe file that is created by python
I have developed a program with Python and converted it to an exe file. Then, I used 'Inno Setup Compiler' to convert all files into a setup file. Everything was fine when I started the program until I tried an input process, where I encountered an "attempt to write readonly database" error. I used SQLite3 during the database process. Does anyone have any idea how I can fix this error?
Thanks.

You should check the file permissions on the database file, to ensure that writing is allowed.
